# python f-string include all numbers except 0 while making a file list

Tags: python-3.x, regex, f-string

I want to make a list of files with `extend()` while ignoring any file name ending with 0 as in `_file0.h5`. I have this line for concatenating all the files into a list

```
data_files_0.extend(sorted(glob(f"{directory}*_file{filenum}.h5") ) )
```

I am trying to learn how to implement regex here and I tried

```
    filenum = re.match(r'[^0]')
```

by putting it above the previous line which gives the error
`TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

I am pretty confused here and all the examples of f-string with regex don't help me at all.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` won't automatically look for strings containing that pattern - you have to provide the string to it - that's the cause of the missing argument error.
Example - `re.match('[^0]', "abc0123")` will check for matches in the string "abc0123" according to the pattern '[^0]'.

`[^0]` is likely wrong pattern here since this matches any and every character at any position in the string except for a `0`. You might want to use something like `.*0\.h5`, which matches any string ending with `'0.h5'`. You can also check out [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/), which is a very helpful site for figuring out how regex patterns work in general.

For the other part of the problem - finding the files - you might have to just get all the filenames first, then check which ones end with 0 or not:

```py
all_files = glob(f"{directory}*_file*.h5")
for f in all_files: 
    if not re.match('.*0\.h5', f):
        data_files_0.append(f)
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I need. I constrained myself too much to find out a particular way, which may not even be exist, couldn't think more obvious solutions. thank you